# How to find key value pairs from imported array? ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following a youtube tutorial, but I want to change an aspect of it. At the moment I'm mapping through an array to retrieve all products. However, I want to retrieve all products with the specific value of "Nike". Many thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Product from "./Product";
import Title from "./Title";
import { ProductConsumer } from "../context";
export default class ProductList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className="py-5">
          <div className="container">
            <Title name="our" title="products" />
            <div className="row">
              <ProductConsumer>
                {value => {
                  return value.products.map(product => {
                    return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
                  });
                }}
              </ProductConsumer>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: just add an if condition inside map, if product.something==='Nike'..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to filter products array for Nike items before using .map() function like this

```
<ProductConsumer>
  {value => {
    return value.products.filter(product => {
      return product.brand === 'Nike';
    }).map(product => {
      return <Product key={product.id} product={product} />;
    });
  }}
</ProductConsumer>
```

Comment: Mate!! thank you so much 